# How do I bring back deliveries where status is X and more recent delivery is status Y?

Tags: sql

I've been struggling away at this and I think I'm in need of a hint!

I have a **delivery_table** for eBooks and in this table are the following columns: **catalogue_number, delivery_date, status_id**

I'm trying to bring back all entries from column **catalogue_number** where the product_status is '4' but only when there is a more recent delivery of the catalogue_number that is at status '1'

Here's an example of what I might see for a particular eBook:

```
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| Delivery_Date | Catalogue_Number | Status_Id |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 12/02/2012    | ABA00001         | 3         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 01/02/2012    | ABA00001         | 1         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 20/01/2012    | ABA00001         | 4         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 18/01/2012    | ABA00001         | 4         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 10/01/2012    | ABA00001         | 3         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 01/01/2012    | ABA00001         | 3         |
+---------------+------------------+-----------+
```

The second from top delivery is at status 1 (ingested) but there are earlier deliveries at status '4' (errored) I want to bring back every cat number at status '4' where this is the case.

I'm guessing it's going to be some kind of nested query scenario but I'm struggling to think up the logic of what the query needs to do!

Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm using SQL Microsoft Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - this will define the subset of orders that have a 1 status and you can then join to your initial query e.g.

```
with Order1Statuses as (
  select Catalogue_number,
         max(Delivery_date) as status1date,
  from delivery_table
  where status_id = 1
  group by catalogue_number
)
select t4.Catalogue_number
from delivery_table t4 inner join Order1Statuses t1 on 
    t4.catalogue_number = t1.catalogue_number 
    and t4.delivery_date < t1.status1date 
    and t4.status_id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks just what I need, only I'm getting the error:> "Column 'delivery_table.strCatalogueNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I've tried various grouping / ordering of the results but I can't get past this error...

Comment: Ah yes - code is untested but should work now, missed the group by - I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was trying to add the group clause on the bottom query! Thank you!! Also don't need the comma on the second line, but I imagine that's just a typo. :)

Comment: P.S - I don't have enough reputation yet to +1 you, but I will when I do :)